# Crop part of image within width x height bounds in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I'm building a Mac OS app in SwiftUI. I have a use case where I must crop part of the image (which is a screenshot) and ensure the cropped part is at least 320x240 and match the aspect ratio if it exceeds.

I have below code so far:

```
func fitImageInRect(_ original: NSImage, rect: CGRect) -> NSImage {
    var originalRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: original.size.width, height: original.size.height)
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0
    if rect.width > rect.height {
        width = rect.width
        if width > 320 {
            let ratio = width / 320
            height = 240 * ratio
        } else {
            width = 320
            height = 240
        }
    } else {
        height = rect.height
        if height > 240 {
            let ratio = height / 240
            width = 320 * ratio
        } else {
            width = 320
            height = 240
        }
    }

    var originX = rect.origin.x
    var originY = rect.origin.y
    
    if originX > (originalRect.width - 320) {
        originX = originalRect.width - 320
    }
    
    if originY > (originalRect.height - 240) {
        originY = originalRect.height - 240
    }

    let thumbnailRect = CGRect(x: Int(originX), y: Int(originY), width: Int(width), height: Int(height))

    guard let ref = original.cgImage(forProposedRect: &originalRect, context: nil, hints: nil) else { return original }
    let cropped = ref.cropping(to: thumbnailRect)

    return NSImage(cgImage: cropped!, size: NSSize(width: width, height: height))
}
```

The goal is as follows:

1. If the `rect` size is 150x50, then the cropped photo be 320x240 with `rect` at center of it.
2. If the `rect` size is 640x50, then the cropped photo be 640x480 with `rect` at center of it.

But somehow, the code is behaving otherwise. The final output is seemingly from a vertically flipped `thumbnailRect` and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What is the `rect` parameter that you pass in?

Comment: It's smaller area in the image e.g., 150x100 that I want to be centered in a thumbnail of 320x240 size cropped out of 1920x1080 screenshot.

Comment: Ok, so we can assume that it's smaller (or equal) to the image size

Comment: 100%, yes. It will always be smaller than 1920x1080 but can be smaller or bigger than 320x240

Comment: I played around with this a bit and while I didn’t solve the problem I did notice that when printing `ref` the size values of the CGImage was much larger than the original image which makes me believe the issue is with how `ref` was created.

Comment: Yeah, I did some debugging too. ```NSImage size 3024.000000x1964.000000 actually was 6048x3928 on CGImage
Cropping to 320.000000x240.000000 on 92.302368,1724.000000``` Seems like the cgImage created from screenshot's `NSImage` is double the size. So the rect is not vertically flipped, it's that the `CGImage` is too large and it starts from bottom on `NSImage`'s farthest `y` origin.